# CasperJS, scrape content in the target page with javascript disable

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, casperjs

I want get the content of attribute 'src' of all image from a page of my website. 
I can do this with this simple code :

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

var casper = require('casper').create({
        verbose: true,
        logLevel: "debug",
});

casper.start('http://mylocalwebsite.com', function() {
        var urls = casper.getElementsAttribute(x('//img'), 'src'); // "Google"
        console.log(urls); // urls are displayed in my shell
});

casper.run();
```

But, I want disable javascript when I use my script, I modify my initial code by :

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

var casper = require('casper').create({
        verbose: true,
        logLevel: "debug",
        pageSettings: {
          javascriptEnabled: false,
        },
});


casper.start('http://mylocalwebsite.com', function() {
        var urls = casper.getElementsAttribute(x('//img'), 'src'); // "Google"
        console.log(urls); // this log doesn't appears from my shell
});

casper.run();
```

(property 'javascriptEnabled' set to false)

But If I do that, my script stop working just after the getElementsAttribute line.

I understand this , I can't use a casperjs selector when I disable javascript. Is it right ? Is not possible to disable javascript and scrape element in my page ?

Is there a way for get src content attribute of all images from a script where I disable javascript ?

Thank you !

Comment: Um, if you disable Javascript, and Casper runs on Javascript...then you're disabling Casper. Right? And why would you want to disable Javascript anyway?

Comment: You mean you want to use something you have disabled?

Comment: I want use casperJS but I want prevent all 'no-casperJS' javascript used by the website =) (if its possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent all js of the website from running, by canceling such requests:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  verbose: true,
  logLevel: "debug",
});

casper.on('resource.requested', function(requestData, request){
  if (/\.js/.test(requestData.url)) {
    casper.log("skipped " + requestData.url);
    return request.cancel();
  }
});
```

and keep js enabled for casper.

js files might not have `.js` suffix in their URL, if resource files are not required, you can also cancel all resource request.